# Using Datatables to export a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use Datatables to export a table.

The problem I run into is that I have the following table:

```
<table id="tbl" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-field="ID">ID</th>
<th data-field="Name">Name</th>
<th data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents"></th>
</tr>           
</thead>

<tr data-index="0"><td class="sorting_asc" style="">1</td><td class="sorting" style="">asadasd</td><td class="sorting" style="">-</td></tr>
<tr data-index="1"><td class="sorting_asc" style="">2</td><td class="sorting" style="">qwqweqwe</td><td class="sorting" style="">-</td></tr>
</table>
```

I use this to add the buttons to export:

```
$('#tbl').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
} );
```

This will always export only 2 rows. No matter how many I add to the table with javascript.

Deleted the clone thing since that's not what I'm actually doing.

I populate the table with ajax:

```
function Load_ObjectList() {
    var url = urlService + "/TESTLoadAgencies/0";
    var EmpCode = sessionStorage['EmpCode']
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        data: "{\"Empcode\":\"" + EmpCode + "\"}",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Status == "0") {

                if (response.list != null) {
                    objDataAll = response.list;
                    $('#tbl').bootstrapTable('destroy');
                    $('#tbl').bootstrapTable({

                        data: objDataAll,
                        escape: 'false'
                    });
                }

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

After I call this function I add the buttons. And 0 rows are copied when I press the button.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It only exports the two rows you added manually in the table because you are clonning the last line after datatable is initialized. You should do it before.

If you want last row to be in the exported files, first clone the row and then initialize your datatable like this:

```
    var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();
    $trLast.after($trNew);

    $('#tbl').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: That did actually work, so thanks.
But I am getting the data with ajax, and it doesn't work even if I add the buttons after